# Configuring Gradle + Robolectric

Tags: java, android, gradle, robolectric, build.gradle

I'm starting to use gradle and robolectric.

I'm following this example:

http://www.peterfriese.de/android-testing-with-robolectric/

However, he complains the lack of JUnit and Roboeletric classes.

Below is my file build.gradle and some prints

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
        classpath 'com.squareup.gradle:gradle-android-test-plugin:0.9.1-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-test'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {


    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        instrumentTest.setRoot('src/test')
    }
}

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'

    instrumentTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
    instrumentTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3-SNAPSHOT'
    instrumentTestCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3-SNAPSHOT'
    testCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add build type `debug` (correctly to say you need to have different from release build type). It is square test plugin requirement as well as Robolectric test plugin (https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/robolectric/gradle/RobolectricPlugin.groovy#L42).

Modify your `build.gradle` to next:

```
buildTypes {

        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }

        debug {
        }

}
```

And don't forget to switch Android studio to debug variant:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. My problem was to be using IntelliJ and not the Android Studio. Learned that there are problems regarding the integration of it with gradle.